# How to write a lambda expression to create a burndown chart

Tags: c#, linq

My goal is to create a burndown chart.

I have a fault object with the following relevant fields:

- FaultID
- FaultCreationStartDate
- FaultClosedDate

I have create a list which returns list of day between two given dates

```
List<DateTime> listOfDays = new List<DateTime>();
        int lastDayOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(i_Date.Year, i_Date.Month);

        for (int i = 1; i <= lastDayOfMonth; i++)
        {
            listOfDays.Add(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,
                                   DateTime.Now.Month, i));
        }
```

Now i want to get the in each day the number of faults that are open, it's means that they haven't been closed.

Basically the `FaultClosedDate` should be > than the relevant `day`

I have created some linq expression but it doin inner join and not left join.

I want to get all days in the month and to count all opened faults in that day

```
var tryfaults = listOfDays.SelectMany(d => i_Context.Faults.GetAllFaults()
                .Where(f=> f.FaultCloseDateTime >= d.Date), (d, f) => new
                {
                    Date = d.Date,
                    Open = f.FaultID
                }).GroupBy(d => d.Date).Select(d => new
                    {
                        Date = d.Key.Date,
                        Open = d.Count()
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
var allFaults = i_Context.Faults.GetAllFaults();
var faults = 
  listOfDays.Select(d => new { Day = d.Date,
                               OpenFaults =
                                   allFaults.Count(f => f.FaultCloseDateTime >=
                                                           d.Date)
                             });
```

Comment: Thanks!, i don't know why i wend for difficult solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't see something, but isn't it just:

```
var tryfaults = listOfDays.Select(d => new {
                    Date = d.Date,
                    Open = i_Context.Faults.GetAllFaults().Where(f=> f.FaultCloseDateTime >= d.Date).Count())
                }).ToList();
```

But I have to say - you general idea for that query is highly inefficient.